# Flag/close/share questions/answers?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

Are moderator tools, specifically flagging or voting to close going to be implemented in the Android app? If we have a dispute, we should at least have the flag option.

What about share option? If we would like to share a question, we could long press on the question title, and the question title, excerpt, and short URL copied to clipboard.

Comment: the share should ideally bring up Android's share intent.. then again I don't have access (yet) to the App so no idea what it does

Comment: We do play on supporting basic flagging.  This will be completed closer to the beta phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag/share option now exists in the Android app.

Follow the images:

[image: hidden button1]

[image: hidden button2]

[image: hidden button3]