# How can I raise flags from Android Stack Exchange application

Tags: support, flags, android-app

While I am browsing through few Stack Exchange sites from official Android application, I can't find a way to raise flags on invalid posts. How can I do that?

Comment: Based on [Flag/close/share questions/answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191336/flag-close-share-questions-answers), it looks like that it is not yet available and is [status-planned].